# How to integrate Restfull API with smart contract using c#?

Tags: eosjs, eosio-code, api, eosio.system, c#

I am new to **EOSIO**. I referred eos.io for learning. Now I need to learn how to integrate API with a smart contract. I am willing to do this in c#. I got answers mostly for **eosjs** which is used in nodejs, any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ping me on tg if you need help, my tg-handle is cmadh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EosSharp](https://github.com/GetScatter/eos-sharp) and [EosWsSharp](https://github.com/cmadh/EosWsSharp) and [EosDotNet](https://github.com/eosnewyork/EOSDotNet) are what you looking for.

EosSharp and EosDotNet are based on the normal RPC-API, EosWsSharp uses dfuse.io for real-time websocket-connections.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestions.

Comment: pls mark as solved if it solved your question.